# Returning nan(ind) when M is big

Tags: c++

When `M` is big it returns `sum_payoff = nan(ind)`. I don't understand why and this only when `M` is really big.

```
int M = 50000;

double K = 32; // Strike price

double r = 0.05; // Interest Rate

double sigma = 0.2; // Underlying's volatility

double T = 5.0 / 12.0; // 5 Months Maturity

double sum_payoff(0.0);

for (int i(0); i < M; i++) {

double S_T = S*exp((r - pow(sigma, 2))*T + sigma * sqrt(T)*rand_normal());

sum_payoff += max(S_T - K, 0.0);

cout << sum_payoff << endl;

}

cout << "Sum payoff : " << sum_payoff << endl;
```

PS : `rand_normal()` return a random number following a standard normal law N(0,1).

Comment: check max values for `int` type

Answer (score 0):

your counter `i` is of type `int` which can only hold up to certain range [Datatypes ranges](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm), if `M` is bigger than this range, the value of `i` won't make sense and you may get negative values which will mess up the whole loop.

Also when you assign a value larger the datatype range, it will get truncated. 
for example

```
int M = 99999999999;
std::cout<<M; // it won't be 99999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
int M = 50000;
```

represents your definition of a big number, I'd say you have a bug in rand_normal or are not using the max() that you expect, or have failed to initialize S and your compiler isn't defaulting it to zero.

If rand_normal() is correct and S is a valid value, sum_payoff should be about 10% higher than 50000 * S, based on the code you have.

Reasoning: all of the terms within exp(...) except rand_normal() are constant, reducing the assignment line in your loop to

```
double S_T = S*exp(0.004166 + 0.129099*rand_normal());
```

This gives an input range of 0.004166 to 0.133265, with corresponding exp() output range of 1.004175 to 1.142553.  Since S is not modified by the loop, the result will on average be about 10% higher than 50000 * S, whatever S is (assuming it is > 0).

Check to verify that it is calling the max() function you expect to be called; there could be multiple max() definitions in different namespaces, depending on what you are using to build this.  If the wrong max() is being called, the results could be unpredictable.

Check the definition of rand_normal, since unexpected results such as a divide-by-zero error stored as a nan(ind) could carry through the computation if you have floating point exceptions turned off (or are using a compiler that doesn't support them).

If neither of those are the problem, double-check your definition of S (whatever data type it is) and make sure it is initialized correctly and that 50000*S is not big enough to overflow a double data type.